# Python to get Rgb of mesh faces

Tags: python, faces, bmesh

This is my first use of Python in blender, although I have had Python experience elsewhere some time ago (Arcpy).

I have a mesh object with several faces that has a material calculated for each face using a complex node group that I am utilising from another licensed coder.

I know that the faces are all a block colour and not a mix of different coloured pixels.

Having selected the mesh, I would like to get the RGB (or hex) value for each face. This would allow me to manipulate the output colours without compromising the complicated node group.

I am struggling with the operators and types in bmesh to get this info. I have seen some solutions online but all seem to be using a very old version of Blender Python and have not worked. Anyone have a 2.83 solution to this issue?

Cheers

Comment: Hello, judging by your description would manipulating the colors with cryptomatte in the compositor after rendering be sufficient ?

Comment: I need to look into that. Not got to that level of blender knowledge yet so need to learn about cryptomatte